# How to assign the objects of a large dict to smaller dicts in a particular ratio?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts which looks like this:

```
{"1":{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}, 
 "2":{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}, 
 "3":{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}, 
 "4":{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}} 
 ... 
 ... 
 "100":{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}
```

I need to have three dicts `d1`, `d2`, `d3` with `d1` containing the values of first 20 keys, `d2` containing the values on next 30 keys and `d3` containing the values of the next 50. 
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Help you with what? Where's your code and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Dictionaries have no order themselves, so how would you define the 'first 20' here?

Answer (score 1):

You'd extract the key-value combinations to a list with `dict.items()`, then slice up those combinations into sublists.

You probably want to apply some sorting to this list first; dictionaries *have no order* so what is defined as the first 20 depends on what order you apply yourself:

```
items = sorted(inputdict.items(), key=lambda i: int(i[0]))

d1 = dict(items[:20])
d2 = dict(items[20:50])
d3 = dict(items[50:])
```

This sorts the keys numerically first.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a general function to split dictionnaries into a list of dictionnaries of a given size

```
def split_iterator(iterator, sizes):
    return ((iterator.next() for _ in xrange(size)) for size in sizes)

def split_dictionary(dic, sizes):
    return [{val[0] : val[1] for val in it} for it in split_iterator(dic.iteritems(), sizes)]
```

Then you can use `split_dictionary(your_dict, (20,30,50))` to split your dictionnary. This is safe even for incorrect sizes.

Because dictionnaries have no particular order you can replace `dic.iteritems()` with another iterator on your dictionnary that will introduce some ordering if it is needed.

Comment: Here is the code that I have tried. 

from operator import itemgetter 
keys = json.keys() 
order = list(keys) 
q1 = int(round(len(keys)*0.2)) 
q2 = int(round(len(keys)*0.3)) 
q3 = int(round(len(keys)*0.5)) 
b = [q1,q2,q3] 
n=0 
for i in b: 
    queues = order[n:n+i] 
        
    n = n+i 
    print queues 
    
    for j in range(len(queues)): 
        q = (queues[j], json.get(queues[j])) 
        print q 

By this I am able to get the 3 smaller dicts I want, but can you help me assign them to 3 variables? 
The dicts need not be ordered but it would be better if they are ordered.

Comment: ' [(queues[j], json.get(queues[j])) for j in range(len(queues))] ' gives me a list so I tried to convert it into a dict using dict() and then tried to use d[0], to assign the value to variables. But I get an error saying 
''type' object has no attribute '__getitem__''

Comment: @Anurag: your code as it is not really readable or explanatory (for instance what is `json.keys()` ?), it would be better if you explained in plain english what you have and what you want. You can define dict directly using `{key:value for element in iterator}`, or create a dict and fill it (using `dict[key] = value` for instance) or use the `dict` function on something containing only couples (the first element of each couple will be the key, the other the value) - for instance your list, just make sure `d = dict([ (x, y) for i in t ])`. Still `d = {x:y for i in t}` is much better.